# Magmi won't update images

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I'm using the datapump API - it works fine with my products, but now with updating images it won't work.

This is my array that Magmi doesn't like

```
array(5) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(6) "131017"
  ["image"]=>
  string(76) "/ext/vhosts/site/subdomains/m/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
  ["small_image"]=>
  string(76) "/ext/vhosts/site/subdomains/m/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
  ["thumbnail"]=>
  string(76) "/ext/vhosts/site/subdomains/m/public/importer/../import/NO/A_131017.jpg"
}
```

When I imported my products, this worked fine, but there were descriptions etc. on

I have the following magmi settings:

- using mode - *Update existing items only,skip new ones*
- Image import mode - *override existing images*
- Pre-download check for remote images - *enabled*
- Assign only existing images - *no*

Comment: This question may be a bit better handled at http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks benmarks, did not knew that existed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like its a prerequisite of Magento import (and hence Magmi) that the images should be placed inside the media/import folder. So, regardless of where you run Magmi GUI from, the images should be placed inside the media/import folder. Moreover, if your images lie inside a folder inside media/import, you have to specify that in the import csv as well.

For example your images lie inside manufacturer-A folder, then you would have to also define on the image columns, the relevant folder path i.e. manufacturer-A/imagefilename.jpg

 Plus, please be aware that it is a bad idea to have images named as 1.jpg, 2.jpg. Magento tries to create the subfolders for cacheing purposes using the first two letters in the filename. So a 1.jpg would ideally be placed inside 1/./1.jpg which is not possible because of the dot.

Note that when you define path for the images, it is not needed to define a full path just the relative path **from** the import folder (media/import) so in the example above, it is

`manufacturer-A/image-1.jpg`

**and not**

`/ext/vhosts/site/subdomains/m/sitename/magento/media/import/manufacturer-A/image-1.jpg`

Hope this helps. :-)